# Replace function in SQL Server 2014 adds trailing zeros in Char field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I am upgrading from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2014. I have a SQL task in one of my SSIS packages which produces different results in the two different SQL versions.

This is the SQL I am running in both versions. The column `MfgPartNbr` is a `CHAR(50)` column.

```
Select REPLACE(MfgPartNbr, ' ', '0') NewCol,  MfgPartNbr
From Table
```

The results in SQL Server 2014 are:

```
NewCol                                              MfgPartNbr
04090226000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  04090226                                          
04090481000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  04090481
```

The results in SQL Server 2008 R2 are:

```
NewCol      MfgPartNbr
04090226    04090226                                          
04090481    04090481
```

To add some new information - 
I have the 2008 and 2014 SQL servers setup as Linked Servers (I can access either from either).

So when I run these statements in the SQL 2008 box Management Studio, I am selecting records from both servers. They both do NOT return the zeros.

When I run the statements in the SQL 2014 box Management Studio, I am selecting records from both servers again. However now they BOTH return the zeros.

I am just very, very curious about the difference in behavior.

Comment: What is the data type of `NewCol`?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's doing this is because the column is a `CHAR` type.  `CHAR` will always include the spaces at the end of the field, up to the length it supports. So when you run the `REPLACE()` over it, those extra spaces become `0`s.

To get around this, you should do an `RTRIM()` on the field before doing the replace:

```
REPLACE(RTRIM(MfgPartNbr), ' ', '0')
```

Example of behaviour:

```
Declare @Char Char (50) = 'Hi'

Select  Replace(@Char, ' ', '0') As WithoutTrim,
        Replace(RTRIM(@Char), ' ', '0') As WithTrim
```

---

```
WithoutTrim                                         WithTrim
Hi000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  Hi
```

---

You might also want to consider changing the datatype of the field to a `VARCHAR` instead of a `CHAR` if you don't need/want the overhead and spacial padding of using a `CHAR`.

Comment: I understand how to deal with it. What I would like to know is why the results are different in SQL 2014 and SQL 2008. It adds the trailing zeros in 2014, it does NOT add them in 2008. Thanks!

Comment: @StefanN Are you certain in 2008 it's defined as a `CHAR`, and not a `VARCHAR`?  And if so, what is the length of it in the 2008 version?

Comment: Yes, it is Char in both places, length is 50. I compared the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is it doing in 2008? In your example NewCol is same as MfgPartNbr??

I think during the upgrade your data has been filled with trailing spaces. Replace function is doing its job by replacing spaces with zeros. Try RTRIM() as:

Select REPLACE(RTRIM(MfgPartNbr), ' ', '0') NewCol,  MfgPartNbr
From Table

If this gives you expected result then you may want to Update all MfgPartNbr values with RTRIM (MfgPartNbr)

Comment: Half of this is old (upgraded) data and half of it is new data, getting loaded into a data warehouse. I did update it (removed the zeros), but running this Select statement in 2014 always returns the additional zeros. I know how to deal with the situation, however I'd like to know why it behaves differently in 2008 and 2014.